# Darken an image in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Darken an image in React Native.

**What I want:** I want to make my image appear darker, I don't want to do it by photoshop or anything like that.

**Research so far:** Some suggestions were to use backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)", but that does not work since I am not using ImageBackground. I also have seen the Opacity prop used, but that doesn't work for my scenario.

The closest I got was tintColor, but I wasnt able to change the opacity on that with the prop and RGBA didn't work either.

**The image:** (I want to make my white text pop more!)

[image: The image I want to darken]

**Small code snippet:**

> {/* Image */}
>
> ```
>     <View style={styles.workoutImageContainer}>
>       <Image
>         source={item.photo}
>         resizeMode="cover"
>         style={styles.workoutImage}
>       />
>
>       <View style={styles.workoutTitleContainer}>
>         <Text style={styles.workoutTitle}>{item.name}</Text>
>       </View>
>     </View>
>   </TouchableOpacity>
> ```

Comment: What's wrong with just making sure your content is correct to begin with?

Comment: You could try a filter library like https://github.com/iyegoroff/react-native-image-filter-kit

Comment: @DrewReese I was using the image elsewhere, I didn't want to have multiple versions of the same photo. :)

Comment: @osekmedia ah thanks, this is cool!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reduce the opacity of the image and wrap it in a black-ish container.

This is not darkening in a photo editing maner, where you would keep brighter whites. This is plain fade to black.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
}

img {
  opacity: .6
}
```

```html
<div>
 <img src="https://www.placecage.com/320/200"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying to apply a CSS filter rule. [Brightness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#brightness) is the one I think you would want. I do know some CSS rules have limited support in React-Native though.

```css
img.darker {
  filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"/>
<img class="darker" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"/>
```

Here's an [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@drew.w.reese/darken-an-image-in-react-native), but yeah, appears to not work so well on the native side so you'll likely need to resort to using an overlay or similar approach.